# SKAction.move(to: ...) and SKAction.move(by: ...) does the exact same thing for me

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skaction

I've set up an SKScene, that I fill with a bunch of blocks. Upon touch I want to move a random block to the 0,0 position of the SKScene. 0,0 is not the final goal, but I use it for test. My node is called a bixel and I naturally thought that using SKAction.move(to: ...) would move it to an absolute coordinate, as stated in the documentation, however I must be missing something, as moving to 0,0 does nothing, however moving to say 100,0 moves it 100 pixels to the right.

I've tried all the move(to: ...) (moveTo(x: ...) etc. And I've tried move(by: ...) which works as it should.
With the code provided below, if I switch between action and action2 (by rebuilding the project), the outcome is always the same, it's moved 100 pixels to the right.
I've also tried the point convert:
`let point = self.convert(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), to: bixel)`
but the result is the same.

```swift
let bixel = bixels[Int.random(in: 0..<bixels)] bixel.fillColor = .red

let action = SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 0), duration: 0.1)
let action2 = SKAction.move(by: CGVector(dx: 100, dy: 0), duration: 0.1)
bixel.zPosition = 1000
bixel.run(action)
```

EDIT: You are completely correct @Martin R. And as I wrote in my comment to your answer every ShapeNode thought that their position was 0,0. It was because of how I initialised them.
I did this:

```
let bixel = SKShapeNode(
    rect: CGRect(
        x: xOffset + (xF * shapeSize.width),
        y: self.size.height - yOffset - (yF * shapeSize.height),
        width: shapeSize.width - space,
        height: shapeSize.height - space
    ),
    cornerRadius: 2
)
```

Which made it think it's position was 0,0. So when I just changed it to this:

```
let bixel = SKShapeNode(rectOf: shapeSize, cornerRadius: 2)
bixel.position = CGPoint(
    x: xOffset + (xF * shapeSize.width),
    y: self.size.height - yOffset - (yF * shapeSize.height)
)
```

everything worked. Thanks!

Comment: The second method specifies the movement relative to the current position. It makes no difference if the current node position is (0, 0).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`SKAction.move(to:duration:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skaction/1417768-move) creates an action that moves a node to the given position.

```
SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 0), duration: 0.1)
```

creates an action that moves a node to position `(100, 0)`.

[`SKAction.move(by:duration:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skaction/1417739-move) creates an action that moves a node relative to its current position.

```
SKAction.move(by: CGVector(dx: 100, dy: 0), duration: 0.1)
```

creates an action that moves a node from its current position `(x0, y0)` to the new position `(x0+100, y0)`.

Both actions have the same effect if (and only if) the current node position is `(0, 0)`.

Comment: Yes, I thought I understood that, from what I read that's how it's supposed to work. However for me this is the same for all 326 nodes, all in different locations. If I do: `SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), duration: 0.1)` for example, they all stay where they are. And if I do: `SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 0), duration: 0.1)` they all move 100 pixels to the right.

EDIT: Huh, for some reason even though they are all scattered throughout the scene, they all "think" that their position is 0,0. So you are definitely right! I just have to find out why they "think" that.